# Architecture mismatch when installing pg gem 0.14.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, pg

I was trying to do a bundle update in Mountain Lion while this weird error jumped out:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wlicpsc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg_connection.c:2064: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wlicpsc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
pg_connection.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg_connection.c:2594: warning: ‘rb_thread_select’ is deprecated (declared at /Volumes/MacintoshHD/Users/wlicpsc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
compiling pg_result.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: in /opt/local/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /opt/local/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1
```

... OK sorta long, but the key is here: /opt/local/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib seems to have a mismatch of architecture. I have checked similar questions which was about libssl, but this one is even more rare. I am not using Brew. Any suggestions? Thanks very much.

Comment: After you upgraded to 10.8, did you [migrate your MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) installation?

Answer (score 1):

First install postgresSQL with OS X installer: 
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Then install postgres gem with that command (just remember to change the version (9.1) to yours:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/ gem install pg
```

Comment: Tried it, looks like not working, the same error persists. The problem is on some files about libsasl which seem to need a patch or something. Thanks for the response though.